# Скрипт проверки поля на наличие символов. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, border

Доброго времени суток.
Делаю сайт с регистрацией. Вот код на HTML и CSS.

```css
/* INPUT STYLE */

.email:invalid, .password:invalid {
    outline: 3px solid rgba(232, 41, 41, 0.4);
}

.email:valid, .password:valid {
    outline: 3px solid #00bc0e;
}

.email:focus:invalid, .password:focus:invalid {
    outline: 3px solid #00bebe;
}



/* SIGN IN */

#signin {
    width: 38%;
    max-height: 370px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.sign {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30pt;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    color: #9cceff;
}

#goto {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-spacing: 20px 8px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

#link {
    color: #00bebe;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: inherit;
    transition: color .2s linear;
}

#link:hover {
    color: #016668;
}

#sign_tab {
    width: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.email {
    width: 240px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #c5cfff;
}

.password {
    width: 240px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #c5cfff;
}

.write {
    color: #9cceff;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

#in {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #0031a0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    padding: 15px 40px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    text-align: center;
}

#in:hover {
    background-color: #00006f;
    color: #cccccc;
}

#into {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
                        <form action="data/html/SignIn.html" target="_blank">
                            <div id="sign_tab">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="email" class="write">Email</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="email" id="country" name="email" class="email" maxlength="40" placeholder="Your email.." required>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="password" class="write">Password</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="password" maxlength="40" minlength="8" placeholder="Your password.." pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,40}"  required>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" id="into">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="in">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </form>
```

Разумеется, пока юзер не введёт пароль или почту в верном формате: поле считается invalid.
Так вот как мне организовать что, если в поле нет символов (ещё не введены, либо стёрты), то поля у него вообще нет. Иначе смотрятся красные поля некрасиво.
Я так понимаю, JavaScript, больше не вижу способов. Помогите с кодом, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что хотите сделать. Скрыть поле, удалить, сделать не активным?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы не было рамки у input'ов

Comment: посмотрите ответ.

Comment: Да, ответ весьма эстетичный, попробую. Будут проблемы - напишу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - такое решение(Со сменой классов):

```js
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var country = document.getElementById('country');
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        var valueC = country.value;
        var valueP = password.value;
        if (valueC == null || valueC == ""){
            country.classList.remove("email");
            country.classList.add("email1");
        } else {
            country.classList.add("email");
        }
        if (valueP == null || valueP == ""){
            password.classList.remove("password");
            password.classList.add("password1");
        } else {
            password.classList.add("password");
        }
    });
```

```css
    .email:invalid, .password:invalid {
        outline: 3px solid rgba(232, 41, 41, 0.4);
    }

    .email:valid, .password:valid {
        outline: 3px solid #00bc0e;
    }

    .email:focus:invalid, .password:focus:invalid {
        outline: 3px solid #00bebe;
    }



    /* SIGN IN */

    #signin {
        width: 38%;
        max-height: 370px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 16px;
    }

    .sign {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30pt;
        font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
        color: #9cceff;
    }

    #goto {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-spacing: 20px 8px;
        border-radius: 16px;
    }

    #link {
        color: #00bebe;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: inherit;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-weight: inherit;
        transition: color .2s linear;
    }

    #link:hover {
        color: #016668;
    }

    #sign_tab {
        width: inherit;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .email {
        width: 240px;
        max-width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        max-height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 15px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #c5cfff;
    }
    .email1 {
        width: 240px;
        max-width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        max-height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 15px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #c5cfff;
    }

    .password {
        width: 240px;
        max-width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        max-height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 15px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #c5cfff;
    }
    .password1 {
        width: 240px;
        max-width: 250px;
        height: 30px;
        max-height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 15px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #c5cfff;
    }

    .write {
        color: #9cceff;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    }

    #in {
        width: auto;
        background-color: #0031a0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 15pt;
        margin: 20px 0 0;
        font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
        padding: 15px 40px 8px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #in:hover {
        background-color: #00006f;
        color: #cccccc;
    }

    #into {
        text-align: center;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<form action="data/html/SignIn.html" target="_blank">
    <div id="sign_tab">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="email" class="write">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" id="country" name="email" class="email1" maxlength="40" placeholder="Your email.." required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="password" class="write">Password</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="password1" maxlength="40" minlength="8" placeholder="Your password.." pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,40}"  required>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" id="into">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="in">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Отлично, всё сделал, всё работает. А Вы не могли бы помочь с выпадающим меню? (делаю оптимизацию под смартфоны)

Comment: @KoryJaxx а что необходимо?

Comment: чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меню плавно вниз "выезжало" меню с 4-мя элементами.

Comment: @KoryJaxx нужен пример разметки, чтобы с нуля не писать. Оформите вопрос, если ещё не создавали.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071253/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b5