# Выпадающее меню на страничке

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, menu

Появилась необходимость сделать выпадающее меню на странице — делаю оптимизацию под смартфон.
Но не знаю как сделать. Пытался, не выходит. Есть только иконка меню, а как сделать дальше — не знаю.

```js
//menu.js
function DoIt(icon) {
  icon.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
/* BODY */

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* SMART MENU */

#SmartMenu {
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: auto;
  /*    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.6);*/
}

#MenuIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 30px;
}

#strip1,
#strip2,
#strip3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.change #strip1 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(11px, -11px);
}

.change #strip2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.change #strip3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 11px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="SmartMenu">
    <div id="MenuIcon" onclick="DoIt(this)">
      <div id="strip1"></div>
      <div id="strip2"></div>
      <div id="strip3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="data/js/menu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ещё есть проблема, что на самом смартфоне не отображается вообще ничего, из того, что прописал в .css файле. Перекидываю архив на телефон — не работает. Тоже непонятно.

Comment: Работает, только там, как я вижу, замена символа. "=" меняется на "x".

Comment: Появляется, но я хотел, чтобы плавно выезжало вниз.

Comment: Нет, впервые слышу о таком.

Comment: Отправил письмо

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо бы css покрасивше сделать.
 Но если по сути - выпадающее меню можно реализовать так:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".toggle").click(function(){
            $("#SmartMenu").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
 /* BODY */

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }


    /* SMART MENU */

    #SmartMenu {
        top: 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 98%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        height: auto;
        /*    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.6);*/
    }

    #MenuIcon {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px 30px;
    }

    #strip1,
    #strip2,
    #strip3 {
        width: 35px;
        height: 25px;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: .3s;
    }
    .change #strip1 {
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(11px, -11px);
    }

    .change #strip2 {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .change #strip3 {
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-11px, 11px);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a class="toggle" href="#">Тык</a>
<div id="SmartMenu">
    <div id="MenuIcon">
        <div id="strip1">Параметр1</div>
        <div id="strip2">Параметр2</div>
        <div id="strip3">Параметр3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Хотел ещё отметить, что у Вас в примере `div` с классом `SmartMenu` не отображается на странице, так как стоит `display:none;`. По этому невозможно было нажать кнопку. Либо надо делать hidden, либо другую кнопку(добавил в примере)

Comment: Всё дело в том, что я забыл упомянуть. Тут оно "display: none;", а в @media(1160px) "display: flex", "align-items: center;", "justify-content: flex-end;" (чтобы было справа).

Comment: Скопировал, почему-то не работает...

Comment: С мобилы не робит